# Linux: resize application window to fit display

Tags: xorg, qt3

I have a 1024x768 Qt3 application, and want to run it on a smaller tablet display. Isn't there a way to zoom out the application window, so to fit the display? I mean: not resize widget by widget, but at very low level, frame by frame, as if it were a video. The window should respond to mouse and keyboard, obviously.
Thank you!
John

Answer (score 1):

you can start x11vnc server where your qt3 app is running and vnc client on the tablet

```
x11vnc -id qt3_app_window_id -scale required_scale -geometry 1024x768
```